# Fixed header, parallax hero image below, smooth scroll iOS and no JS

Tags: css, scroll, parallax

**So close yet so far** - I'm trying to mock-up something close to the BBC News app but with a **fixed header** bar. Like the BBC, it's then a parallax image below, then the content.

Issues I can't resolve

1/ Smooth scroll on iOS. I've used this:

```
* { -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
```

But it breaks the parallax on iOS. The image doubles in size and no parallax in scrolling anymore. Take it out and it works but is jerky.

2/ The fixed header only seems to be fixed on narrow screen width like phone, anything wider it scrolls out of view.

I'm not totally against JS but only if necessary and it's very lightweight and unobtrusive.

Here's my fiddle/code: https://jsfiddle.net/tobzzzz/aq9Laaew/120148/

Answer (score 0):

Parallax is usually terrible for performance, especially on mobile. Perhaps you should ask yourself if this is adding anything to your user's experience. If not, maybe it shouldn't be there.

To solve your fixed header issue and some jankiness, just move the nav up and out of your wrapper which you set to 100vh. 
https://codepen.io/IanHazelton/full/a4ff387ebb94eb332c37dabe1de99235/
Don't forget to section things semantically and give ARIA roles & descriptions. BBC are accessibility leaders.

```
<header>
    LOGO
    <div class="nav-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
</header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: I hear you - parallax is very 2013 as well, but it just looks nice in the BBC app context. If it *can't* be done, so be it but now it's become a challenge to try. Yes, that example will fix the sticky header but breaks the parallax even further. Essentially I could build the whole thing without heights and without the webkit-overflow-scrolling required, it would just smoothly scroll, so it doesn't really fix this.